# Google Authentication with Xamarin Forms app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-authentication

I've been looking all day for a nice and easy way to integrate Google authentication in a Xamarin Forms app. I've tried a couple of methods but since Google doesn't allow in-app browser view authentication anymore, all of the methods are deprecated (giving error 403, disallowed_useragent).
I had no idea that doing something this simple could become so hard.

There are methods I haven't tried yet, but they require platform specific code (code from before Xamarin Forms) and I don't want that, I want it to be directly cross-platform.

It appears that no one has an SDK for this. Anyone else figured it out?

Comment: I moved to doing this via "native" implementations on each platform. For Android you basically are required to use Chrome `CustomTabs` now, if you are looking for a `Xamarin.Android` example/port of the Google example, I ported the code to C# : https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.GoogleChrome.CustomTabs.Shared For OAuth, I wrote it myself using CustomTabs and SFSafariViewController for Android and iOS.....

Comment: @SushiHangover I was afraid this would be the only solution. Thank you...

Comment: There is an open issue with `Xamarin.Auth` to update to using CustomTabs and SFSafariViewController but I've seen zero progress in terms of PRs against the repo :-( Personally it is not that hard to take the original `Xamarin.Auth`  sourceand convert it while also adding things like auto-refresh tokens, etc.... that is what I based my original port on...

Comment: Too bad. This should be a default right for developers to have this

Comment: @SushiHangover  can we somehow use the google sign in button in xamarin.android in xamarin forms application

Comment: have you ever found a good solution for that?

Comment: @batmaci As SushiHangover suggested you should move it to the native part